# How to change the Firebase Emulator Hub port?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

When running the Firebase emulator, I get the following port information.

```
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator       │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth      │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions      │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore      │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Storage        │ 127.0.0.1:9199 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/storage   │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150
```

I can set all ports in the `firebase.json` like so:

```
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    ...
  }
```

But that doesn't work for the `Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400`. (I want storybook to use port 4400)

```
  "emulators": {
    "hub": {
      "port": 4401
    },
```

This seemed to be implied by the [Hub Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#use_the_emulator_hub_rest_api)  response. However, when I start the emulator, it simply deletes my `hub` configuration.

**Is there a way to change the Emulator Hub port?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the port in firebase.json like so:

```
"emulators": {
    ...
    "hub": {
      "port": 9222
    }
  },
```

```
$ firebase emulators:start
...
Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:9222
```

> However, when I start the emulator, it simply deletes my hub configuration.

This sounds like a bug. If you can provide a minimum reproducible example the team can take a look:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose

Comment: yep. I forgot I had a script updating the firebase.json on start

Comment: Is there a way to set ports outside of firebase.json? eg with env vars? Problem is different team mates need to have ports configured differently, but it looks like the file itself  should still be shared in the repo.

Comment: Right now there isn't a way to specify the ports with environment variables. The project is open source though so you could add the behavior.